# USB 3.0 flash drive has slow performance after reformatting

Tags: performance, usb-flash-drive, ntfs, usb-3

I bought a USB 3 flash drive, and after a few weeks of using it (happily), I needed a bootable linux and that was the only thing handy.  So I reformatted it and worked through all that jazz. But I'm using it again, and it seems to be performing at USB 2 speeds.

I'm not sure what's causing it, because it's still formatted as an NTFS drive, but the speeds are just so. freaking. slow.

Do I need to format it again or something?

Comment: Aren't these usually formatted with exfat or fat32? NTFS overhead usually comes with a price.

Comment: If I recall, it was formatted with NTFS because it's 16GB and exfat and fat32 have limitations on file size (which isn't cool with me, since I need to move large files).

Comment: exFAT limitation is volume size (recommended 512 Terabyte max). FAT32 is the one that's limited

Comment: exFAT is a modern file system MS created for USB sticks specifically. It is far better for them than NTFS and it does not suffer from the 32bit limitation
Most likely to switched your format from exFAT to NTFS which is why you are having a slowdown

Answer (score 2):

Could be a sector mis-alignment, try formatting it with [SD Card Formatter](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/), if no specific tool is advised by your USB flash manufacturer.